# mysql: insert from table previous value +1

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I am trying to insert data from two tables into a new table and that part I have working. At the same time I am adding a counter. I cannot use auto_increment because it is not the primary key. It cannot be the primary key because the counter will reset regularly and numbers will duplicate. The code that I have is

`INSERT INTO new_table (data1, data2, counter)
 SELECT firsttable.data1, secondtable.data2, counter+1
 FROM firsttable,secondtable,new_table
 WHERE firsttable.data1='x'
     AND secondtable.data2='y'`

The counter jumps up one number on the first line and then stays at that value for every other line. How can I get the counter to increment by one for each following line?

Comment: Please post your real insert statment. It's hard for us to debug something that isn't the actual code you are running.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Typically a count is something you would calculate in your query

Comment: @SamM, this is essentially, the real statement, because I am putting in through phpmyadmin. The only things that I changed are the names of the tables and columns because I thought they would be confusing. If it is helpful, the actual code is 'INSERT INTO resident_newmover (resident, campaign,new_id)
     SELECT resident.id, campaign_num_type.id, new_id+1
     FROM resident,campaign_num_type,resident_newmover
     WHERE resident.date='2018-02-06'
     AND campaign_num_type.num='3''